# What are the implications of flipping the op-amp inverting and non-inverting inputs in an inverting amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

[image: Typical Setup]

\$V_{out}=G(V_2-V_1)=G(0-V_1)=-G\cdot V_1\$

\$i\cdot R_F=V_1-V_{out}=\frac{V_{out}}{-G}-V_{out}\$

\$i\cdot R_{in}=V_{in}-V_1=V_{in}-\frac{V_{out}}{-G}\$

\$R_F\cdot V_{in}+\frac{R_F}GV_{out}=-\frac{R_{in}}GV_{out}-R_{in}\cdot V_{out}\$

\$V_{out} = \frac{R_F}{-R_{in}-\frac{R_{in}}G-\frac{R_F}G}V_{in}\$

and as G is large

\$V_{out} = -\frac{R_F}{R_{in}}V_{in}\$

[image]

\$V_{out}=G(V_1-V_2)=G(V_1-0)=G\cdot V_1\$

\$i\cdot R_F=V_1-V_{out}=\frac{V_{out}}G-V_{out}\$

\$i\cdot R_{in}=V_{in}-V_1=V_{in}-\frac{V_{out}}G\$

\$R_F\cdot V_{in}-\frac{R_F}GV_{out}=\frac{R_{in}}GV_{out}-R_{in}\cdot V_{out}\$

\$V_{out} = \frac{R_F}{-R_{in}+\frac{R_{in}}G+\frac{R_F}G}V_{in}\$

and as G is large

\$V_{out} = -\frac{R_F}{R_{in}}V_{in}\$

Comment: One is an inverting amplifier, and the other becomes a Schmitt-Trigger comparator. The one with the negative feedback will do what it can to keep V+=V-, but the one with the *positive* feedback, will either sit at +Vcc or Vss at the output.

Comment: For the 2nd circuit (the Schmitt-Trigger), think what happens if Vin = + 1 V and the gain of the opamp (used as a comparator) is 1 million. Assume that Rin and Rf have the same value. What would be the output voltage? What is a **realistic** output voltage? Do the formulas still apply without restrictions? (Hint: no).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Vin = 1V, Vout = -1V, V1 = 1microvolt, following my second derivation. I know there is a problem with my analysis, but can't find it.

Comment: I think there is an error in equation 4 for the second circuit. I would start withe the KVL loop equation. First question is, how many loops (meshes) does this circuit have? :-)

Comment: @RichS I got equation 4 from combining equation 2 and 3 for the second circuit. Can you find a mistake in 2,3 or how I combined them?

Comment: @Big6 If the clipping values are +Vss and -Vss, will the second circuit act as an inverting amplifier when the Vin is maintained within the clipping region? I think the disadvantage is that the inverting quality is lost if the Vin magnitude is too large.

Comment: For the Schmitt-Trigger: *Vin = 1V, Vout = -1V, I know there is a problem with my analysis, but can't find it.* The problem is that the first equation: \$V_{out} = G (V_1 - V_2)\$ doesn't apply anymore as the amplifier will **clip**. To make that equation apply, \$V_{out}\$ must become larger than **+infinite** which is impossible. Now analyse again but assume that -5 V < \$V_{out}\$ < + 5 V. So if  \$V_{out}\$ needs to be + infinite Volts, it will be + 5 V.

Comment: Negative feedback ( diagram1) forces the error, (V2 - V1), towards zero. Positive feedback (diagram 2) does the opposite; it drives the output voltage towards +/- infinity, but it only gets as far as the +ve or -ve rail supply (if it's lucky). So there are incorrect assumptions in your equations for diagram 2. For instance, you have: V1= Vout/G, which can't possibly happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to gain intuition behind what's happening, you need to think of an opamp as a *dynamic* system, that is, the output in response to the input won't instantaneously change from one state to another. Keep that in mind.

Let's assume that \$R_F=R_{in}\$, \$V_{in}=-1V\$, \$V_{cc}=10V\$, and \$V_{ss}=-10V\$. Ideally, the linear range is between 10V and -10V. In the case of negative feedback, when the input is first applied, and say that the output is at 0V, the output will start to rise towards +1V but as it does so, recall that,

$$V_{out} = A(V^+-V^-) $$

which means that if \$V_{out}\$ rises, so does \$V^-\$ as it is fed from the output node, and thus the difference \$V^+-V^-\$ decreases. That slows down the output voltage because the difference grows in the ***opposite*** direction relative to the output and therefore *counteracts* it to keep it in check. This is happening dynamically, and will continue until equilibrium. What this tells you is that negative feedback adjust the the difference between the inverting and noninverting inputs to keep a steady output.

In the case of positive feedback, when the input is first applied (\$V_{in}=-1V\$), the output will respond by trying to go more negative, but notice that in this case, the same negative voltage is fedback to the noninverting input and therefore, the difference \$V^+-V^-\$ becomes more negative. So it grows in the ***same*** direction as the output, and the cycle will continue on and on until \$V_{ss}\$ is reached.

You could reverse the polarity of the input voltage and go through the exercise to see that the same idea holds.

So, as soon as you see net positive feedback present in an opamp circuit, you should disregard the idea the it will function as a linear amplifier. As I mentioned in the comments, the positive feedback circuit you have does have nice applications -- look up Schmitt trigger circuits on the web for more details on how it works.

Comment: This helped, because I see there is no stability for the second circuit to act as an inverter.

Answer (score 2):

You should also try to get intuition for how positive feedback behaves.

Imagine an ideal op-amp with output limiting at the supplies and gain of 100,000.

Input of 0V and we have gain of 100,000 * 0V = 0V output. That seems to fit your equation.

But suppose we apply +1uV. The input will see Rf/(Rin + Rf) * 1uV. The output will go to +10^5 times that, say +50mV. But now the input sees +(1uV/Rin + 50mV/Rf)(Rin*Rf/(Rin+Rf), which is considerably more than +1uV. The output is driven to a voltage which *adds* to the applied input. So the output quickly slams to the positive rail.

The mirror image happens if you apply -1uV, the output quickly slams to the negative rail.

The ideal op-amp is effectively sitting on a knife edge with 0V in. In reality it will never sit there (computer simulations might, however, allow such a state).

The positive feedback no longer has any effect once the output saturates and the inputs will no longer be even approximately at the same voltage.

As a comparator, there will be two transition voltages, one when the output voltage is railed at the positive limit and another when the output voltage is railed at the negative limit. At those transition points the output comes out of saturation briefly and slams to the opposite rail as the positive feedback takes effect. That is the Schmitt trigger working. Image below is from [here](https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/electrical-engineering/schmitt-trigger/)

[image]

Comment: The formulas and derivation in the picture don't really have anything to do with a Schmitt trigger. It's still the inverting amplifier with mistaken + and -. Assuming Va=0 is invalid with positive feedback i believe.

Comment: @Spehro Pedhany Ok, this helps me see the, instability in the operation as an inverting amplifier, so even if we start within the bounds of my second derivation, the circuit is forced to clip, and never acts as an inverting amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in my derivation in the question, is I assumed for the second circuit \$V_{out} = G \cdot V_{1}\$, which doesn't hold when \$V_{out}\$ is clipped. So the second circuit behaves as a comparator.